# Make Enter create newline in Eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

In Eclipse's C/C++ editor, I have the option enabled to automatically close `(`parentheses`)` and `[`square brackets`]`.  This works well except when I want the contents to span more than one line.  When one or more closing characters have automatically been created, pressing Enter just moves the cursor to the end of those closing characters.  So if I want to type out the code

```
if ( f() > 1 &&
     g() )
```

formatted just like that, then pressing [Enter] immediately after typing `&&` doesn't start a new line, and it's not obvious how to easily get that formatting.  The best I've come up with is [Esc] then [Enter], but then manually closing by pressing `)` inserts another character instead of moving forward past the existing one.

Is there a way to get [Enter] in this context to do what I want?  Or is there some command I can bind to a single key (like Shift+Enter or Ctrl+J) to just insert a newline and auto-indent?  Ideally I would still be able to skip an auto-created `)` by typing `)`, but a single key similar to [Esc] then [Enter] would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a key binding that you can use to insert a new line below / above the existing line. You can see that if you go to Window -> Preferences -> Keys. There you can find the key binding for the "Insert Line Below Current Line" and "Insert Line Above Current Line" commands.

You can modify the key binding to the keys with which you are comfortable with or you can create a new key binding and make it reflect to this action (when using own key binding, you can also make it reflect to the C/C++ Editor by choosing "C/C++ Editor" instead of the general "Editing Text" option in **When:** combo). However, I do not think it is possible to bind both the new line and the auto indent actions to one particular key binding a in a straight forward way using user preferences.

Comment: Thanks, but I did see those commands.  I want to insert the newline between the expression so far and the `)` or `]`, not before or after the entire line.